# Azure Devops YAML: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

With Azure DevOps YAML task "Invoke-HTTP", I keep getting 
`Exception message 'Exception Message: Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: -. Path '', line 1, position 8. (type JsonReaderException)'`

Here is the documentation of task:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

The script is as follows:

`jobs: 
  # Publish resource group artifact
  - job: invoke_http_for_ase
    pool: server
    continueOnError: true
    steps:
      # Invoke REST API
      # Invoke a REST API as a part of your pipeline.
      - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
        displayName: 'GET Member'
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'connectedServiceNameARM'
          azureServiceConnection: 'ARM-Service-Connection'
          method: 'GET'
          headers: '{Content-Type:application/json}'
          urlSuffix: "subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx?api-version=2018-05-01"
          waitForCompletion: 'true'`

And the same works from the designer with the Release Task within the release pipeline.

Comment: so which character is that? or you dont know?

Comment: I am suspecting the parameter: azureServiceConnection, trying it out with no special characters..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that the headers value must be valid JSON, i.e. property names and values must be enclosed in quotes. See [this github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/9618)

Answer (score -1):

Indentation is your problem. Scoot every line below "jobs:" to the left, ie:

`jobs: 
- job: invoke_http_for_ase
  pool: server
  continueOnError: true
  steps:
  # Invoke REST API
  # Invoke a REST API as a part of your pipeline.
  - task: InvokeRESTAPI@1
    displayName: 'GET Member'
    inputs:
      connectionType: 'connectedServiceNameARM'
      azureServiceConnection: 'ARM-Service-Connection'
      method: 'GET'
      headers: '{Content-Type:application/json}'
      urlSuffix: "subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx?api-version=2018-05-01"
      waitForCompletion: 'true'`